# In *nix, can we source a script only for one command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Inside a shell script i need to call a java program which requires a set of environment variables to be set using a script, since the java program will be inside a loop and the source script that sets the env will change in each iteration, the environment variables set by the previous iteration interferes with the next iteration.

I do understand there is a way to set variables only for the current command only [ VAR1=value myScript ]. Can the same be done with script as source instead of a variable.

Comment: execute the command in a subshell by wrapping the code in `(...)`. E.g. `( VAR1=value; some other commands )`.  You can assign the result using either **command substitution** e.g.  `result=$(VAR1=value; some other commands )` or use the output on `stdin` with **process substitution** `while read -r line; do suff; done < <(VAR1=value; some other commands )` **note:** the `space` between `< <(` is required. You can source a file at any point in your script. You can wrap the section in `braces {..}` and limit the scope to that section.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by David C. Rankin use a subshell:

```
(source ./your_script; ./your_java_program)
```